# Probability of a particle being at a given energy level in a discrete canonical set

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, probability, partition-function

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)), the canonical partition function for a system of discrete and non-degenerate energy levels at temperature $T$ is defined as

$$Z=\sum_{i} \mathrm{e}^{-\beta E_{i}}$$

where $i$ indexes the microstates of the system and $E_i$ the total energy of the system when it is in the $i$-th microstate. Then, the probability that the system is in the $s$-th microstate would be

$$P_s= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\beta E_{s}}}{Z}$$

Let's suppose we have a system of $N>>1$ particles and three discrete energy levels $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3$, and that we want to find the number of particles in each level, $N_1,N_2,N_3$.

Could this probability $P_s$ be transformed in a certain way to get the probability of a particle being in each of the three energy levels?

Comment: When your system is in contact with a heat bath of temp. T, $P_s$ is the probability of a particle being in $E_S$. Do you expect to know something more about the system?

Comment: Ok but, according to Wikipedia, $P_s$ is not the probability that a particle is in the energy level $\varepsilon_s$, but the probability that the whole system is in the microstate that gives an energy $E_s$.

Comment: Are your particles distinguishable?

Comment: The statement of the problem does not specify it, it only indicates that there is no degeneration.

Comment: This is a homework-like problem. Please try to solve it without help.

Comment: @user266148 Talking about the system, there is no microstate for which the energy of the system is $E_s$ for s=1,2 or 3. Energy of the system is the sum of the energies of the particles.i.e. E(system)=$N_1*E_1+N_2*E_2+N_3*E_3$ where $N_s=P_s*N$